# Why can't I `print __doc__` in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
"""

USAGE:

    apache_logs.py 

"""

import sys
import os


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not len(sys.argv) > 1:
        print __doc__
        sys.exit(1)
    infile_name = sys.argv[1]
```

I get an error that says

```
Tue Jul 21{stevenhirsch@steven-hirschs-macbook-pro-2}/projects/python:-->./apache_logs.py 
  File "./apache_logs.py", line 17
    print __doc__
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why? The documentation I've read all seems to suggest it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of Python do you have? In Python 3, [`print` was changed to work like a function](http://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) rather than a statement, i.e. `print('Hello World')` instead of `print 'Hello World'`

I can recommend you to keep using Python 2.6 unless you're doing some brand new production development. Python 3 is still pretty new.

Comment: Right, no one should be using Python 3.x yet unless they have a really good reason.

Comment: It's fine to use Python 3.x for small hobby projects, as long as you're aware that most of the 3rd-party Python libraries haven't been ported yet.

Comment: Wahnfrieden, why should 'no one' use Python 3.0.  If it's library support, you've got a serious chicken and the egg problem.  If 'no one' should use it then no libraries will be ported.  I'd recommend using Python 3 if you accept the library limits, if you don't, then you should use 2.6.

Comment: Developing a Python library is a "really good reason" to be using Python 3.x, so my point stands. Basically, if you have to ask, then Python 3.x isn't for you, yet, but maybe in a year or two. For learners, 2.6 already has some important 3.0 features backported to it, so it's a much better starting place.